# Iterating $x^x$

Tags: special-functions

If we set $f(x):=x^x$, then the iterations of $f(x)$ follow a steadily increasing in the complexity of the function as shown by https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wpgpilljhg.

The iterations also show a very nice order to them, with their steadily increasing.

This begs me to ask the question, what is the general function $g(n,x)=f^n(x)$? Not sure what tags to use, if you know, add them and delete this part please.

Comment: Iterated exponentiation is called tetration. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Comment: That's not exactly what I had in mind. If you look at the Desmos page you'll see it isn't just $x^{x^x}...$

Comment: $g(2,x)=(x^x)^{x^x}\neq x^{x^{x^x}}$

Comment: @helloworld112358 yes, I misunderstood the question slightly. The proof that this function is not elementary would follow in the exact same manner as that of tetration though. So at the end of the day, there isn't going to be a 'nice' form for  $g$.

Comment: Could there be a way to calculate g for specific n's?

Comment: "what is the general function": it cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions and you must do with the recursive definition $g(n,x)=g(n-1,x)^{g(n-1,x)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your reference is wrong from $f_3(x)$ on. The correct expression is $$
f_3(x) = \left(x^{x^{1+x}}\right)^{x^{x^{1+x}}}=x^{x^{1+x}\cdot x^{x^{1+x}}}=x^{x^{1+x+x^{1+x}}}
$$
I think that the best you can have is a recursive formula: the general term is
$$
f_n=x^{x^{p_n}}
$$
with $p_1=1$; then
$$
p_{n+1}=p_n+x^{p_n}
$$
so that the first terms are
\begin{align}
p_1=&\ 1\\
p_2=&\ 1+x\\
p_3=&\ 1+x+x^{1+x}\\
p_4=&\ 1+x+x^{1+x}+x^{1+x+x^{1+x}}\\
\vdots&\\
\end{align}

Comment: What you expanded is $f_3$, not $f_2$.

Comment: Oh yes, I've corrected it, thank you! @Yves